# Access variable outside of function Swift

Tags: swift

How can I get the value from firstName from the inside:

```
func saveImage(name: String, postURL:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())){

    //Get sspecific document from current user
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")

    var firstName = ""

    // Get data
    docRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in

        var firstName = ""

        if let err = err {
            print("ERROR: ")
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else if querySnapshot!.documents.count != 1 {
            print("More than one documents or none")
        } else {
            let document = querySnapshot!.documents.first
            let dataDescription = document?.data()
            firstName = dataDescription?["firstname"] as! String



        }

    } 


//         This uploads the data

    let dict = ["title": postDescriptionTitle.text!,
                "description": postDescription.text!,
                "Address": addressField.text!,
                "Zipcode": zipcodeField.text!,
                "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"],
                "Author":firstName,
                "postUrl": postURL.absoluteString]
        as [String: Any]
    self.ref.child("post").childByAutoId().setValue(dict)

}
```

It looks like it's out of scope, how can I store it or access it without storing it in another variable?

As you can see, I'm trying to upload the variable **firstName** to the database. So in this part: 
"Author":**firstName**,
I should be getting the value so I can give it to Author

Comment: Why does this function not use its completion block? Why does the completion block provide a `url` parameter that you don't use? Why not update (and use) the completion block to return the first name value you want? Or why not move the "upload" code inside the block that has the first name?

Comment: I'd like to do it this way, so I can reuse it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the "upload data" part inside the completion block like this:

```
  func saveImage(name: String, postURL:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())) {
        //Get sspecific document from current user
        let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")

        // Get data
        docRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in

            if let err = err {
                print("ERROR: ")
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            } else if querySnapshot!.documents.count != 1 {
                print("More than one documents or none")
            } else {
                let document = querySnapshot!.documents.first
                let dataDescription = document?.data()
                let firstName = dataDescription?["firstname"] as! String
                //         This uploads the data
                let dict = ["title": self.postDescriptionTitle.text!,
                            "description": self.postDescription.text!,
                            "Address": self.addressField.text!,
                            "Zipcode": self.zipcodeField.text!,
                            "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"],
                            "Author": firstName,
                            "postUrl": postURL.absoluteString] as [String: Any]
                self.ref.child("post").childByAutoId().setValue(dict)
            }
        }
    }
```

Also for what are you using the completion argument in your saveImage function?